# Tensorflow randomly won't load at all

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i have been trying to run the basic tensorflow quickstart, but can't manage to do it

i followed closely the basic instructions, and randomly, i end up with :

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "F:\developpement\ai\tensorflow.py", line 3, in <module>
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'
```

when importing the module (`import tensorflow`)

i have python 3.6.8, and executing exactly these instructions : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#virtual-environment-install

it's extremely inconsistent, sometimes it loads, and i'm able to run the quickstart, but most of the time it returns the error above, for no apparent reason
[image: shell of inconsistent behavior of tensorflow]
it is the right version of tensorflow installed (2.4.1), and keras is installed as well (2.4.3)

can you help me ?

Comment: It is a very very bad idea to call your script tensorflow.py, as it shadows the real tensorflow package.

Comment: oh, i've been stuck like a moron because of that, thanks a lot, i was going insane because of that

Answer (score 0):

This is not a random problem. It happens because you have a script called `tensorflow.py` in the folder, which shadows the real tensorflow package and produces those errors.

It is a very bad idea to name a python script the same as a well known package.